# How to increase line width?

Tags: arcpy, symbology

I have a script that changes the symbology to unique values, but I can't figure out how to adjust the width?

```
#isolate the symbology of the selected layer
sym = lyr.symbology #set the symbology as unique values
sym.updateRenderer('UniqueValueRenderer')
#specify the desired fields for the symbolizing
sym.renderer.fields = ['Attribute']
#select a colour ramp
colorRamp = aprx.listColorRamps("Voxel Tracks")[0]
#set the colour ramp
sym.renderer.colorRamp = colorRamp
#update the layer symbology
lyr.symbology = sym
symbol = lyr.symbology
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout the Esri docs for Python CIM [here](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/3.1/arcpy/mapping/python-cim-access.htm).

I'm assuming it's ArcGIS Pro and version 3.0+

Here is an example. The definition described below is like JSON. I reccommmend setting symbology manually and then saving as a lyrx file, open this lyrx with a notepad and you can see the definition (under renderer)

```
## get the definition, like JSON. 
cim_lyr = lyr.getDefinition('V3')

## access the classes for the grouped symbology
group_classes = cim_lyr.renderer.groups[0].classes

## for each symbology class
for group_class in group_classes:
    ## access the symbology
    symb = group_class.symbol.symbol.symbolLayers[0]
    ## set the width to whatever number you want here
    symb.width = 4

## update the definition
lyr.setDefinition(cim_lyr)
```

Comment: Arc 2.9 and changing it to ('V2') everything worked, thank you!